# How to add text after link on windows server 2008 that this link will work

Tags: php, web

Please tell me how to add some text after my address e.g.

**www.domain.ff + some-text-to-add = www.domain.ff/some-text-to-add**

and link return page without error.

My tools:
Windows server 2008, IIS7, PHP.

Where can i set it or where looking for some info?

Comment: Did you try typing the text into the PHP file where the link is, and saving the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now i understand everything about this.

This is redirecting things for IIS7 and i was configured web.config rules in my project directory in this way.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="some_name">
       <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/$" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}?idspec={R:2}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

and i can add anything after my link.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is stored in a variable, you could do:

```
$domain = 'www.domain.ff';
$result = $domain . '/some-text-to-add';
```

Which would result in : `www.domain.ff/some-text-to-add`

Comment: Yes, thanks but its not working when i launch this link on browser.

Comment: its working when i do www.domain.ff/index.php/some-text-to-add

Comment: Okay, this suggests you may have some rewriting going on in your application/.htaccess, based on this you would use a slight change to my answer: `$result = $domain . '/index.php/some-text-to-add';`

Comment: ok it looks good:) but how to set it in htaccess RewriteRule artykul,([_0-9a-z-]+),([0-9]+).html index.php?idspec=$2

Comment: thanks for your try to help me, but i find out some information, nevertheless you was helped me a little